# There do I Implement an PHP Array in Angular project

Tags: php, angular

Hello currently my problem is that I'm trying to implement an simple `PHP array` into my `Angular` project. How can I do this ? I don't know there I have to put my php array, I saw that people put it in there `HTML` but it doesn't work:

```
<?php $linechartvalue = array(0, 10, 70, 2, 100, 30, 45); ?>
<?php echo $linechartvalue[0]; ?>
```

there do I have to put it in my Angular project ? thanks in Advance.

Comment: Create backend endpoints in php for Angular in json format

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? How should the resulting markup look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is kinda confused ... In an Angular project, usually, you make api calls to backend which will return the requested data. Then you can manipulate that data into your Angular components. Here is two links you should check out :

https://www.phpflow.com/php/create-php-restful-api-without-rest-framework-dependency/

https://angular.io/guide/http

That said, if your just need this array `[0, 10, 70, 2, 100, 30, 45]`, you could just declare it as a constant in your Angular component, you don't need php at all

here is an example :

```
export class HeroListComponent implements OnInit {

    linechartvalue = [0, 10, 70, 2, 100, 30, 45];

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {}

}
```

in your component template :

```
<h2>Chart Value List</h2>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let value of linechartvalue">
    {{value}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer instead of linking to external ressources

Comment: sorry for the confusing question but i dont know how I can describe it better. but I'm trying to simulate an call to n `PHP Server` that return me the data (Array of numbers) but I dont know there I have to put this. I tried putting it in my `HTML` but it doesn't work and then in my `.ts` file but it dosnt work either. I hope you can understand my question better

Comment: I that case you should definitely check out the first link, skip everything about the database and in the `case 'GET':` you could just `echo` your static array. I hope it's enough information for you to start, you have some learning to do :)